# Simplify using laws of indices: $\frac{\sqrt{1-x}\,\frac12(1+x)^{1/2} + \frac12(1-x)^{-1/2} \sqrt{1+x} }{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Simplify using the laws of indices:
>
> $$\frac{\sqrt{1-x}\,\frac{1}{2} (1+x)^{1/2} + \frac{1}{2}(1-x)^{-1/2} \sqrt{1+x} }{1-x}$$

I tried factorizing it using surds and I am stuck

Comment: You should write your equation instead of posting an unsearchable image.  [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will help you. Also, could you include some of your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: tries a few laws of indices such as reciprocal rule such that (1-x)^-1/2 becomes (1/1-x)^1/2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is of low quality.

Answer (score 0):

Split into two terms,$$\begin{align}\tfrac12(1-x)^{-1/2}(1+x)^{-1/2}+\tfrac12(1-x)^{-3/2}(1+x)^{1/2}&=\tfrac12(1-x)^{-3/2}(1+x)^{-1/2}(1-x+1+x)\\&=(1-x)^{-3/2}(1+x)^{-1/2}.\end{align}$$You're free to write that in other ways of your choice, e.g. $(1-x^2)^{-3/2}(1+x)$ or $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}(1-x)^{-1}$.

Comment: you ommited the squareroot  on the first expression

Comment: @ZakariaAbdullahi Were some of your $\tfrac12$s meant to be exponents, so that at one point a fourth root is taken?

Comment: no, I believe you solved the equation as required by the picture thanks. also is that the final answer after complete factorization

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\sqrt{1-x} \frac{1} {2} (1+x)^{\frac{1} {2}} + \frac{1} {2}\sqrt{1+x} (1-x)^{\frac{-1} {2}} }{1-x}=\frac{1}{2} ((1-x)^{-\frac{1} {2}} (1+x)^{\frac{1} {2}} +\sqrt{1+x}(1-x)^{\frac{-3}{2}}) .  =\frac {1} {2} \sqrt{1+x}(1-x)^{\frac {-1}{2}}((1+(1-x)^{-1})=\frac {1} {2} \sqrt{\frac{1+x} {1-x}} ((\frac{2 -x}{1-x})$